# Not able to go on with the Request object and callback mechanism of scrapy spider-crawler

Tags: python, callback, request, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and python.This is my spider-crawler

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from tutorial.settings import *
from tutorial.items import *

class DmozSpider(Spider):

   name = "dmoz"
   allowed_domains = ["m.timesofindia.com"]
   start_urls =    ["http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        torrent = DmozItem()
        items=[]
        links = sel.xpath('//div[@class="gapleftm"]/ul[@class="content"]/li')
        for ti in sel.xpath("//a[@class='pda']/text()").extract():
            yield DmozItem(title=ti)
        for url in sel.xpath("//a[@class='pda']/@href").extract():
            yield DmozItem(link=url)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.my_parse)

    def my_parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        self.log('A response from my_parse just arrived!')
        for text in sel.xpath("//body/text()").extract():
            yield DmozItem(desc=text)
            pass
```

here i am trying to collect all the urls that are in tag  and then calling my callback function but code fails to enter my_parse function. Am I missing something.

This is my console log

```
root@yogesh-System-model:~/pythonTest/tutorial# scrapy crawl  dmoz -o mypune13.txt
2014-02-06 16:15:01+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2014-02-06 16:15:01+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto,     django
2014-02-06 16:15:01+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':    'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'mypune13.txt',   'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2014-02-06 16:15:01+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:  HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware,   DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Spider opened
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-02-06 16:15:02+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html> (referer: None)
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Front Page'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times City'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Nation'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Auto Expo 2014'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Global'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Editorial'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Business'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Sport'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Pune Times'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'NEWS DIGEST'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Cong denied Pranab chance to be PM: Modi'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Mom, daughter badly hurt in mishap at theme park'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'13 Indians now head major global firms,4 studied at St Stephens'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'9.7cr new voters added across India in 5 years'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Exit bond money for AFMC grads hiked up to Rs 30 lakh'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'SC revisiting death sentences, stays 3 more'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Jr college teachers call off HSC exams boycott plan'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Tourists from 180 countries to get visa on arrival now'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'50 of 58 new Rajya Sabha members are crorepatis'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'2G spectrum bids touch Rs 50,000 crore'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Discoms loss may be Tata Powers gain'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Colleges, schools work till last min to give hall tickets'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Front Page'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times City'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Nation'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Auto Expo 2014'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Global'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Editorial'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Business'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Times Sport'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'title': u'Pune Times'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Front+Page&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Front+Page&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'mobiletoi.timesofindia.com': <GET http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Front+Page&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Front+Page&edname=&publabel=TOI>
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Times+City&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Times+City&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Times+Nation&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Times+Nation&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Auto+Expo+2014&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Auto+Expo+2014&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Times+Global&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Times+Global&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Editorial&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Editorial&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Times+Business&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Times+Business&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Times+Sport&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Times+Sport&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Pune+Times&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Pune+Times&edname=&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?article=yes&pageid=3&sectid=edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune&edname=&articleid=Ar00300&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?article=yes&pageid=3&sectid=edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune&edname=&articleid=Ar00301&publabel=TOI'}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/htmldbtoi/TOIPU/20140206/TOIPU_articles__20140206.html>
{'link': u'http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?article=yes&pageid=3&sectid=edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune&edname=&articleid=Ar00302&publabel=TOI'}    
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Stored jsonlines feed (62 items) in: mypune13.txt
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 279,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 11226,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 10, 45, 3, 542688),
 'item_scraped_count': 62,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 66,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 10, 45, 2, 127946)}
2014-02-06 16:15:03+0530 [dmoz] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Not sure how your question code formatting reflects the actual code, but it seems you're not indenting the `def parse` and `def my_parse` portions correcly. They have to be aligned with `start_urls`, `name` etc. These callbacks methods must be attributes of the spider class

Comment: Yes name,start_urls,parse and my_parse they all are in line, program runs fine and i get all the titles and links from the parse function but it does not enter the my_parse function and i don't get the description of the links that i get in parse function

Comment: Did you check the domain of the Requests? do they belong to `m.timesofindia.com`? can you relax the domain to "timesofindia.com"? Can you share your console log?

Comment: Your code have mixed tabs and spacing, it can cause unexpected results. Configure your text editor to insert spaces when you hit `[TAB]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console log shows that your request for `http://mobiletoi.timesofindia.com/mobile.aspx?sect_articles=yes&sectname=Front+Page&edid=&edlabel=TOIPU&mydateHid=06-02-2014&pubname=Times+of+India+-+Pune+-+Front+Page&edname=&publabel=TOI` was filtered

```
Filtered offsite request to 'mobiletoi.timesofindia.com'
```

Scrapy has an [`OffsiteMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware) on by default:

> This middleware filters out every request whose host names aren’t in the spider’s allowed_domains attribute.

You need to include 'mobiletoi.timesofindia.com' in `allowed_domains`, like this:

```
allowed_domains = ["m.timesofindia.com", "mobiletoi.timesofindia.com"]
```

Otherwise, Scrapy spider middleware `OffsiteMiddleware` will receive your requests that were yield with `yield Request(url, callback=self.my_parse)` and say that domain doesn't match, and will discard them, with no callback being called at all.

Comment: changing domain from 'm.timesofindia.com' to 'timesofindia.com' worked.....But why was is not entering the my_parse callback..? STill din't got that...though problem is solved....

Comment: Replaced wrong DupeFilter mention with `OffsiteMiddleware` which is the one at work here.

Comment: Ok that means it fails at this 'yield Request(url, callback=self.my_parse)' this request object call itself because the url I am passing here is out of the permissible domain right..?...thank you....

Comment: Well, `yield Request(url, callback=self.my_parse)` does not *fail* itself, but when these `Request`s arrive at the Scrapy spider middleware `OffsiteMiddleware`, the target domain is analyzed and yes, the domain is not in the spider's `allowed_domains` list, so it gets discarded.